# Captured images are not saved into SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I started a `camera` intent :

```
    public class OngletParcelleListeBatiments extends Activity {

        ...

        public void launchCamera(View v) { // called on click of a button

            Uri fileUri = CameraUtil.getOutputMediaFileUri();

            if (fileUri.equals(Uri.EMPTY))

                displaySDError(); // a DialogView

            else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CameraUtil.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CameraUtil.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // User cancelled the image capture
                } else {
                    // Image capture failed, advise user
                }
            }
        }

        ...
    }

    public class CameraUtil {

        public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

        private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PhotosProjetImpotsLocaux"); 
// I already set the first argument to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) but it didn't work !

                if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                    if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png");

                return mediaFile;

            }

            return null;
        }

        public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
            Uri ret = Uri.EMPTY;
            try {
                ret = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                ret = Uri.EMPTY;
            }
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

The SD card is already inserted into the tablet and is mounted. The problem is that at runtime after capturing a photo then the image is inside the `internal storage` but not inside the SD card ! So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: What is the path of `Uri fileUri`?

Comment: @shkschneider How to know that ?

Comment: breakpoint, logcat, anything... It comes from your own `getOutputMediaFile()` method.

Comment: I cannot do that because I run the app on a tablet , and the tablet's driver is not found by my windows7 computer.

Comment: Well I guess the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra does not point to where you want it (external). But since you cannot debug your app I can't help you more. Also a `Toast` would have worked...

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PhotosProjetImpotsLocaux");
```

to

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PhotosProjetImpotsLocaux/" );
```

EDIT:
and add this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work : image is still in internal storage !

Comment: show value of this `mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png"`

Comment: add Log.e("uri",mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png") and paste here

Comment: WTF? add `Log.e("uri",mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png"` above `File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png");
`

Comment: I showed it inside a Dialog and it gives : /storage/emulated/0/PhotosProjetImpotsLocaux/IMG_20150424_171451.png